# c++14 Variadic lambda capture for function binding

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm currently reading a few books to get caught up on c++14 features.  I am trying to use a variadic template to bind arguments to a function.  I know how to do this using std::bind, but I would also like to implement this function with a c++14 lambda expression, just for common knowledge and understanding, and for any possible performance benefits.  I've read that lambdas can be inlined while std::bind cannot inline because it takes place through a call to a function pointer.

Here is the code from myFunctions.h:

```
#include <functional>

int simpleAdd(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

//function signatures
template<class Func, class... Args>
decltype(auto) funcBind(Func&& func, Args&&...args);

template<class Func, class... Args>
decltype(auto) funcLambda(Func&& func, Args&&...args);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//function definitions
template<class Func, class... Args>
inline decltype(auto) funcBind(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    return bind(forward<Func>(func), forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class Func, class ...Args>
inline decltype(auto) funcLambda(Func && func, Args && ...args)
{   //The error is caused by the lambda below:
    return [func, args...]() {
        forward<Func>(func)(forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Here is the main code I am running:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include "myFunctions.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "Application start" << endl;
    cout << simpleAdd(5,7) << endl;

    auto f1 = funcBind(simpleAdd,3, 4);
    cout << f1() << endl;

    //error is occurring below
    auto f2 = funcLambda(simpleAdd, 10, -2);
    cout << f2() << endl;

    cout << "Application complete" << endl;
```

Error   C2665   'std::forward': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Error   C2198   'int (__cdecl &)(int,int)': too few arguments for call

I think the error might be occurring when the variadic arguments are getting forwarded to the lambda, but I'm not really sure.

My question is how do I properly formulate this code so that I can use a lambda to capture the function and its arguments, and call it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read that lambdas can be inlined while std::bind cannot inline
>   because it takes place through a call to a function pointer.

If you pass `simpleAdd` to something that then binds the arguments, then whether you use `bind` or not doesn't matter. What do you think the lambda captures with `func`? It's a function pointer.

The lambda-vs-function-pointer case is about writing `bind(simpleAdd, 2, 3)` vs. `[] { return simpleAdd(2, 3); }`. Or binding a lambda like `[](auto&&...args) -> decltype(auto) { return simpleAdd(decltype(args)(args)...); }` vs. binding `simpleAdd` directly (which will use a function pointer).

---

In any event, implementing it is surprisingly tricky. You can't use by-reference capture because things can easily get dangling, you can't use a simple by-value capture because that would always copy the arguments even for rvalues, and you can't do a pack expansion in an init-capture.

This follows `std::bind`'s semantics (invoking the function object and passing all bound arguments as lvalues) except that 1) it doesn't handle placeholders or nested binds, and 2) the function call operator is always `const`:

```
template<class Func, class ...Args>
inline decltype(auto) funcLambda(Func && func, Args && ...args)
{   
    return [func = std::forward<Func>(func), 
            args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] {
        return std::experimental::apply(func, args);
    };
}
```

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) has an implementation of `std::experimental::apply`.

Note that this does unwrap `reference_wrapper`s, like `bind`, because `make_tuple` does it.

Your original code breaks down because `args` are `const` in the lambda's function call operator (which is `const` by default), and the `forward` ends up attempting to cast away constness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Using a lambda capture as apposed to using std::bind is much more complicated than I was expecting.  I tried implementing your code with the implementations of apply and invoke from cppreference.com but I'm getting some more compiler errors:  Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)', as well as Error C2975 '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::make_index_sequence', expected compile-time constant expression.  I will take another look at this later, but for now I will stick with using bind.

Answer (score 1):

You use a tuple:

```
template<class Func, class ...Args>
inline decltype(auto) funcLambda(Func && func, Args && ...args)
{   //The error is caused by the lambda below:
    auto tpl = make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    //Use move just in case Args has move-only types.
    return [func, tpl = move(tpl)]() {
        apply(func, tpl);
    };
}
```

Where `apply` is [defined something like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply):

```
namespace detail {
template <class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl( F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...> )
{
  return f(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
} // namespace detail

template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return detail::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>::value);
}
```

`apply` is a feature of one of the library TS versions. With C++17, `apply_impl` could call [`invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), which would work for any [callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Should the first part of the lambda capture for capturing func actually say "func = forward<Func>(func)" to make sure you properly forward any Rvalues?  And should this also apply in apply_impl, instead of just "f(..." it should say "forward<F>(f)(... " .

Comment: I also get compiler errors when I try this solution, one of them similar to the error I was getting in my question example at the top:  Error C2975 '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::make_index_sequence', expected compile-time constant expression, and Error C2198 'int (__cdecl *const )(int,int)': too few arguments for call.